# Add a row into R data frame with time

Tags: r, addition

I have a dataset which is the interest rate for Brazilian Real. The data looks like this

```
brli
     1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002      2003      2004 
24.350646 28.003333 26.022500 17.199167 17.856667 19.142728 21.970690 15.416151 
     2005      2006      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012 
17.628748 13.932403 10.577253 11.655332  9.278832  8.870439 10.992365  7.907467
```

However, the rate for 2013 is missing. I want to add the specific rate into this data set with the time accordingly, how could i do it? I tried `cbind`, `rbind` for rows but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this really what your data looks like?  A big long vector with dates and rates mixed together?  Perhaps your formatting got messed up when you tried to post?  As it looks now, inserting 2013 data is the least of the barriers that prevent you from using it.

Comment: Could you post `str(brli)` please

Comment: Post the result of `dput(brli)`  to make it reproducible.

Comment: Actually if I import this data into excel, it'd be in column. Download the data from Quandl and it turned out to be like this. For stock indexes which has more column then it's a better format

Comment: > dput(brli)
structure(c(24.350646319358, 28.003333333333, 26.0225, 17.199166666667, 
17.856666666667, 19.142727908451, 21.970690480331, 15.416150966147, 
17.628747668233, 13.932402674746, 10.577252570994, 11.655332257329, 
9.2788317677565, 8.8704393166779, 10.992364815352, 7.9074665016007
), index = c(1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012), frequency = 1, class = c("zooreg", 
"zoo"))

Comment: > str(brli)
‘zooreg’ series from 1997 to 2012
  Data: num [1:16] 24.4 28 26 17.2 17.9 ...
  Index:  num [1:16] 1997 1998 1999 2000 2001 ...
  Frequency: 1

Answer (score 1):

That does not look like an R dataframe would be printed (since there si no rowname). So I made a named vector which would have been displayed like that.

```
> brli <- setNames( scan(text="24.350646 28.003333 26.022500 17.199167 17.856667 
                      19.142728 21.970690 15.416151 17.628748 13.932403 10.577253
                      11.655332  9.278832  8.870439 10.992365  7.907467 "), 
                    scan(text=" 1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002  
                                2003      2004     2005      2006      2007      2008      
                                2009      2010      2011      2012  ",what=""))
Read 16 items
Read 16 items
> 
> brli
     1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002      2003      2004      2005 
24.350646 28.003333 26.022500 17.199167 17.856667 19.142728 21.970690 15.416151 17.628748 
     2006      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012 
13.932403 10.577253 11.655332  9.278832  8.870439 10.992365  7.907467 
> length(brli)
[1] 16
brli[17] <- 23
> names(brli)[17] <- 2013
> brli
     1997      1998      1999      2000      2001      2002      2003      2004      2005 
24.350646 28.003333 26.022500 17.199167 17.856667 19.142728 21.970690 15.416151 17.628748 
     2006      2007      2008      2009      2010      2011      2012      2013 
13.932403 10.577253 11.655332  9.278832  8.870439 10.992365  7.907467 23.000000
```

You should have posted output from `dput(brli)`